# Unable to change user's password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have an MVC 5 Identity 2 app. I'm trying to change a user's password as follows:

```
    public async Task<string> ChangePassword()
    {
        var user = await this.UserManager.FindByIdAsync(18);
        PasswordHasher hasher = new PasswordHasher();

        user.PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword("NewPassword");
        this.UserManager.Update(user);

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

this.UserManager is defined as:

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
```

The method executes successfully, but the password is not getting changed. Am I missing a step?

Comment: UserManager has methods to reset and change password

Comment: @tmg - Gee, could you elaborate a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserManager has these methods to change user's passwords:

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> ResetPasswordAsync(TKey userId, string token, string newPassword)

public virtual Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(TKey userId, string currentPassword, string newPassword);

protected virtual Task<IdentityResult> UpdatePassword(IUserPasswordStore<TUser, TKey> passwordStore, TUser user, string newPassword);
```

Comment: What UserManager is this? It isn't the same UserManager I'm using based on HttpContext.GetOwinContext() because those methods do not exist.

Comment: HttpContext.GetOwinContext() will return you an object of asp.net UserManager yes

Answer (score 0):

I believe UserManager has this handy method:

```
public virtual Task<IdentityResult> ChangePasswordAsync(
    TKey userId,
    string currentPassword,
    string newPassword
)
```

**EDIT:**

This seems to be working for me. A UserManager property is defined as such:

```
public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }
```

Then, the password reset method:

```
//
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }
        var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
        {
            // Don't reveal that the user does not exist
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, model.Code, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: What UserManager is this? It isn't the same UserManager I'm using based on HttpContext.GetOwinContext().

Comment: Plus I have to know the user's current password. And, if I knew that, I wouldn't need to generate a new one.

Comment: Hmm I made a new MVC project just to test it out and I can call ChangePasswordAsync just fine from    

`HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()`

If you're talking about reseting it then there's also `ResetPasswordAsync()`

Comment: I think you misunderstood my post. I have a ResetPassword method in my controller and it works fine. What I'm talking about is the ability for me to change another person's password for them. Can I do this, and how?

Comment: Couldn't you generate your own token and pass it to the password reset method like so?

`var token = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

var result = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, token, vm.NewPassword);`